# Extract word in string in R

Tags: r, string

I have data set with description like this

```
PosID   description
2        Ubiquitin carboxyl-terminal hydrolase 14 OS=Homo sapiens GN=USP14 PE=1 SV=3
2        26S proteasome non-ATPase regulatory subunit 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=PSMD1 PE=1 SV=2
1        Ankycorbin OS=Homo sapiens GN=RAI14 PE=2 SV=1
2        Alstrom syndrome protein 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ALMS1 PE=2 SV=1
1        26S protease regulatory subunit 6A OS=Homo sapiens GN=PSMC3 PE=1 SV=3
1        sp PSMC3_Human 26S protease regulatory subunit 6A OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=3
```

I would like to extract specific word which appear either appears after GN= or after a space in the last case

This is my required output

```
PosID   description
2       USP14
2       PSMD1
1       RAI14
2       ALMS1
1       PSMC3
1       PSMC3
```

**data**

```
df = structure(list(PosID = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), description = structure(c(6L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 5L), .Label = c("26S protease regulatory subunit 6A OS=Homo sapiens GN=PSMC3 PE=1 SV=3", 
"26S proteasome non-ATPase regulatory subunit 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=PSMD1 PE=1 SV=2", 
"Alstrom syndrome protein 1 OS=Homo sapiens GN=ALMS1 PE=2 SV=1", 
"Ankycorbin OS=Homo sapiens GN=RAI14 PE=2 SV=1", "  sp PSMC3_Human 26S protease regulatory subunit 6A OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=3", 
"Ubiquitin carboxyl-terminal hydrolase 14 OS=Homo sapiens GN=USP14 PE=1 SV=3"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("PosID", "description"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Try `sub(".*(?<=GN=)(\\w+).*$","\\1",df$description,perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Or `stringi::stri_extract_first_regex(df$description, "(?<=GN=)(\\w+)")`

Comment: @nicola Wondering if there is any advantage in the (?<=) since `sub(".*GN=(\\w+).*$","\\1",df$description,perl=TRUE)` works too.

Comment: thanks you very much to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option using `str_match` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
out = Reduce('rbind',
             lapply(c("GN=([A-Z0-9]+)\\s", "\\s([A-Z0-9]+)_"), 
             function(x) str_match(df$description, x)[,2])
            )
df$required = out[!is.na(out)]

#df[,-2]
#  PosID required
#1     2    USP14
#2     2    PSMD1
#3     1    RAI14
#4     2    ALMS1
#5     1    PSMC3
#6     1    PSMC3
```

Comment: in some cases I have like this "sp PSMC3_Human 26S protease regulatory subunit 6A OS=Homo sapiens PE=1 SV=3", I wont have "GN" in that case I will be for 2nd character "PSMC3" as output, could you please help me out. Many thanks in advance

Comment: In such cases you could use this `str_match(here_your_string, "\\s([A-Z0-9]+)_")`

Comment: I will edit the answer and update your question, there are experts in here who can give you more straight forward answers, I guess mine is a workaround option not very efficient. In case you get any other answer efficient please consider to accept that

Comment: @Veerandra Is it possible I can do both functions in single command?

Comment: @Jay it is actually a single function which gives a vector output in `out`. In the second command I am simply removing NAs and adding it to the dataframe

Comment: Thank you very much I got it

Comment: @Veerandra I try to use string split,                                                                   head(strsplit(x2, split = "\\ ")[[1]],2)
[1] "sp"          "PSMC3_HUMAN"                                                                 I am getting two values "sp" and "PSMC3_HUMAN", I want only "PSMC3", could you please help. Many thanks in advance

Comment: @Jay sorry could not get back to you. Why do you want to use `strsplit`? Anyways you are getting that because you are splitting the string using only spaces but you need to split also using "_" like this `head(strsplit(x, split = "\\ |\\_")[[1]])[2]`. let me know!