# Extract string from text after matching - regex R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I have an input text

```
   inputQ <- "What can I do ..my baby has rash all over. Suggest good rash cream"
```

I have a list of terms

```
terms <- c("diaper","cloth diaper","rash pants","rash","baby wipes","rash cream")
```

I wish to exact match one of the terms and return it as well
I tried using for loop, but is there a better method

Result should be

```
 rash cream
```

stored in matchedTerm

Comment: Why do you want "rash cream" but not "rash" returned? What did you try?

Comment: *I wish to exact match one of the terms* ... which one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33856148/regex-in-r-extracting-words-from-a-string or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784376/extract-word-in-string-in-r

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to get all the matches, then check for the one with the biggest number of characters:

```
wh_match <- names(unlist(sapply(terms, grep, inputQ)))
wh_match[which.max(nchar(wh_match))]
# [1] "rash cream"
```